# Should I remove Aloe Vera offshoots to enhance growth?

Tags: indoors, aloe

I have 3 Aloe Vera plants that used to be in the same pot. I let them remain in it for too long I presume, since all of them have thin (although full) leaves and long stems. Since they used to give each other structural support they tend to lean to a side now that I separated them.

I would really like them to solidify their roots, gain a firm standing if you will, and of course in the end get thicker leaves and stems.

So far I watered them little to avoid rot and have them in about 6 hours of sunlight a day. Instead of stabilising or thickening their leaves they grow small offshoots now.

Would removing the offshoots help the plant channel more energy into becoming thicc, or is this counterproductive? Any tips would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually thin leaves and long stems usually mean that the plants haven't received enough sunlight, so you should move them to a brighter spot (not to direct sunlight though, they tend to dislike that, their leaves start becoming purple from that), but there's not much you can do about the stems themselves. If in turn you've left them on direct sunlight most of the time then you should move them to a darker spot, because leaving them on the sunlight for too long tends to cause the same symptoms too.

As for your desire to "solidify their roots" that's just never going to happen I'm afraid. Aloe (just like most succulents in fact) has thin, short, shallow and fragile roots which just barely hold the plant firmly on the ground (in fact quite often they don't). They'll never have roots that would come anything close to what woody plants have for instance.

Removing (=tearing off) the offshoots does help with plant development, but only after the sunlight issue is addressed. Without that it doesn't make much of a difference (if at all).